# Android emulator won't start with device ramsize set to 1024

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Hello and thanx in advance. The problem is that when device's RAM is set to 1024 - AVD won't start (I have different virtual devices and issue is common). When set to lower value i.e. 512 it works fine. In eclipse.ini I have 
    -Xms512m
    -Xmx2047m
but I assume this is not connected with Android SDK manager. I'm running Win7x64 with 4GB RAM, swap is 8GB on SSD - has to be enough for this.